# Java Exception appends ": null" to "Caused by" clause

Tags: java, exception

There are some exceptions shown as follows in my log: (the text has been modified to conceal project information)

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:org.xxx.BBBException<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;at ....<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;...<br>
Caused by: org.xxx.BBBException: null<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;at ....<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;...<br>
```

Why is there "null" in the Caused by clause?

BBBException, which was made by us, extends Exception and does not override toString().
In some situations, FutureTask.setException(new BBBException("RPC timed out")) is called and BBBException is being expected in the log.
However, the exception's details message is not what we set in the program and the text in the first line and Caused by clause even do not match (there is no ": null" in the first line).
Anyone has a clue why this has happened? Thanks!

Environment: java 6, update 21, centos 64-bit, java 64-bit, mixed mode.

Comment: I wish the problem was an easy one. Here is a piece code copied from Throwable:
<code>
public String toString()
{
  String str1 = super.getClass().getName();
  String str2 = getLocalizedMessage();
  return ((str2 != null) ? str1 + ": " + str2 : str1);
}</code> so, either ":" comes with a message, or it is missing; unless we pass string "null" as message or override toString() which has things like return ""+field. However, neither is what we have done.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've *either* actually created a new `BBBException` without a message, or your `BBBException(String)` constructor doesn't pass the message up to the super-constructor (which it should, via `super(message)`). Basically it's saying: this is an exception with no message.

It's hard to tell *exactly* what's wrong without seeing any of your code though.

Answer (score 1):

`org.xxx.BBBException: null` was thrown with `null` message (using default constructor). Throw it with some message (if it supports it):

```
throw new BBBException("Danger! High Voltage")
```

If this doesn't work, it means the `BBBException(String msg)` constructor is poorly written. It should be something like:

```
BBBException(String msg) {
  super(msg);
}
```